Why when I try to bucket fill, colour is lighter than it should?
In bump texture painting, I colour pick, but when I try to bucket fill, the resulting colour is lighter, how can I fix this issue?
The strength is set to 1, and I tried to check and uncheck pressure, but nothing changes.


Your answer is a work around and not an answer to WHY, but I see you are using the Image Editor and that explains it - the tolerance level of the tool there has a lot to do with it as well as the 'pressure' being toggled on for the tool in the strength there.

I solved it by creating a new image from shading. I looks like it fails when I create a bump image from properties > tool settings > texture slots.
